# regex matching with multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex

I need to obtain a string of letters from the following **rows_string** variable:

```
'Equity & 1,638 & \\$3,227,305 & \\$2,649,208 & \\$3,270,402 & \\$3,114,298 & \\$3,173,369 & \\$2,978,769 & \\$3,016,161 & \\$2,807,840\\\\\nFixed Income & 420 & \\$765,856 & \\$661,395 & \\$824,603 & \\$792,579 & \\$794,224 & \\$783,793 & \\$719,307 & \\$630,298\\\\\nCommodities & 119 & \\$72,911 & \\$66,302 & \\$81,649 & \\$81,633 & \\$79,296 & \\$76,450 & \\$64,136 & \\$63,667\\\\\nAsset Allocation & 63 & \\$10,190 & \\$9,275 & \\$10,684 & \\$10,089 & \\$10,371 & \\$9,829 & \\$9,619 & \\$8,880\\\\\nAlternatives & 55 & \\$5,601 & \\$6,023 & \\$6,715 & \\$6,279 & \\$6,365 & \\$6,645 & \\$6,757 & \\$6,243\\\\\nCurrency & 34 & \\$311 & \\$2,014 & \\$1,665 & \\$1,743 & \\$1,683 & \\$1,666 & \\$1,722 & \\$2,058\\\\\nTOTALS & 2,329 & \\$4,082,173 & \\$3,394,217 & \\$4,195,718 & \\$4,006,620 & \\$4,065,308 & \\$3,857,151 & \\$3,817,700 & \\$3,518,986\\\\'
```

So for instance, I need the following list:

```
[Equity, Fixed Income, Commodities, Asset Allocation, Alternatives, Currency, Total]
```

I tried:

```
re.findall(r'\\\\\n(\w+.*?) &', rows_string)
```

Great but this omits the `"equity"` variable
And also gives me an empty list for this string variable

```
'Starting Portfolio & sell & 21.39\\% & -0.91\\% & 1.52\\% & 9.29\\% & 9.72\\% & 14.89\\% & 38.21\\% & 55.4\\% &  & 90.86\\%\\\\'
```

So for the second string, I need `['Starting Portfolio', 'sell']`
What I want is to grab the first item following `\\\\\n` and first item before the `'&'` in the string variable.  Thank you

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\\\\\n(\w[^&]*)\b', rows_string)`

Comment: I tried it, didn't work

Comment: Then please provide exact Python code snippet to repro the issue.

Comment: Do you want a match either from the start of the string or a newline? Perhaps like `(?:\\\\\n|^)(\w+.*?) &` https://regex101.com/r/Gl0Ue2/1/

Comment: what?  didn't I already do that?

Comment: @ The fourth bird, I want to match the string names.  anything that comes before the '&'.

Comment: To also match sell you could use `(?:^| & )([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*)(?= &|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/bxEnDP/1

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing one `\`. You are not searching for the letters `\` and `n` but instead for a line break. So just ad `\` at the beginning of your regex. Also you are missing the first entry since you state, that your word starts with `\\\\\n`. To also get the first you could use `^(\w+.*?)|[\\\\\n](\w+.*?) &` for example

Comment: uhh.  so I added another comment.  with: re.findall('\\\\\\n(\w+.*?) &', rows_string) I didn't get equity in the answer

Comment: See edit, you are not checking at the beginning of the string, there is probably a better way to do it, though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reason to focus on the escaped newlines. This should do the trick:

```
import re

pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z]\b'

rows_string = 'Equity & 1,638 & \\$3,227,305 & \\$2,649,208 & \\$3,270,402 & \\$3,114,298 & \\$3,173,369 & \\$2,978,769 & \\$3,016,161 & \\$2,807,840\\\\\nFixed Income & 420 & \\$765,856 & \\$661,395 & \\$824,603 & \\$792,579 & \\$794,224 & \\$783,793 & \\$719,307 & \\$630,298\\\\\nCommodities & 119 & \\$72,911 & \\$66,302 & \\$81,649 & \\$81,633 & \\$79,296 & \\$76,450 & \\$64,136 & \\$63,667\\\\\nAsset Allocation & 63 & \\$10,190 & \\$9,275 & \\$10,684 & \\$10,089 & \\$10,371 & \\$9,829 & \\$9,619 & \\$8,880\\\\\nAlternatives & 55 & \\$5,601 & \\$6,023 & \\$6,715 & \\$6,279 & \\$6,365 & \\$6,645 & \\$6,757 & \\$6,243\\\\\nCurrency & 34 & \\$311 & \\$2,014 & \\$1,665 & \\$1,743 & \\$1,683 & \\$1,666 & \\$1,722 & \\$2,058\\\\\nTOTALS & 2,329 & \\$4,082,173 & \\$3,394,217 & \\$4,195,718 & \\$4,006,620 & \\$4,065,308 & \\$3,857,151 & \\$3,817,700 & \\$3,518,986\\\\'

rows = re.findall(pattern, rows_string)

print(rows)

rows_string2 = 'Starting Portfolio & sell & 21.39\\% & -0.91\\% & 1.52\\% & 9.29\\% & 9.72\\% & 14.89\\% & 38.21\\% & 55.4\\% &  & 90.86\\%\\\\'

rows2 = re.findall(pattern, rows_string2)

print(rows2)
```

Comment: Does not include the `'TOTAL'` in there

Comment: hey this doesn't include totals.  Also.  ['Starting Portfolio'] only.  Rather than ['Starting Portfolio', 'Sell'].  I want all string variables in those strings

Comment: Edited, should include `TOTALS` now

Comment: @rajn Your example contains `sell` in all lowercase.

Comment: I meant 'sell' sorry

Comment: This pattern will not include `sell`

Comment: yep it doesn't.  how do I include 'sell' in this pattern?'

Comment: @rajn For that, you could either dive into something really complicated, or just use the pattern `[A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z]` and deal with ` sell` having a space in front of it.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Word boundaries can help us here. Edited the answer.

Comment: sell is still not in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern with `re.finditer()`:

```
pattern = r"(((?!\\\\\\\\\\n)([a-zA-Z\\s]+))|([a-zA-Z\\s]{2,}\\s?(?!\\&)))"
output_list = [i.group().strip() for i in re.finditer(pattern, rows_string) if i.group().strip()]
```

Inputs :

```
s1 = 'Equity & 1,638 & \\$3,227,305 & \\$2,649,208 & \\$3,270,402 & \\$3,114,298 & \\$3,173,369 & \\$2,978,769 & \\$3,016,161 & \\$2,807,840\\\\\nFixed Income & 420 & \\$765,856 & \\$661,395 & \\$824,603 & \\$792,579 & \\$794,224 & \\$783,793 & \\$719,307 & \\$630,298\\\\\nCommodities & 119 & \\$72,911 & \\$66,302 & \\$81,649 & \\$81,633 & \\$79,296 & \\$76,450 & \\$64,136 & \\$63,667\\\\\nAsset Allocation & 63 & \\$10,190 & \\$9,275 & \\$10,684 & \\$10,089 & \\$10,371 & \\$9,829 & \\$9,619 & \\$8,880\\\\\nAlternatives & 55 & \\$5,601 & \\$6,023 & \\$6,715 & \\$6,279 & \\$6,365 & \\$6,645 & \\$6,757 & \\$6,243\\\\\nCurrency & 34 & \\$311 & \\$2,014 & \\$1,665 & \\$1,743 & \\$1,683 & \\$1,666 & \\$1,722 & \\$2,058\\\\\nTOTALS & 2,329 & \\$4,082,173 & \\$3,394,217 & \\$4,195,718 & \\$4,006,620 & \\$4,065,308 & \\$3,857,151 & \\$3,817,700 & \\$3,518,986\\\\'
s2 = 'Starting Portfolio & sell & 21.39\\% & -0.91\\% & 1.52\\% & 9.29\\% & 9.72\\% & 14.89\\% & 38.21\\% & 55.4\\% &  & 90.86\\%\\\\'*
```

**Output** :

```
['Equity', 'Fixed Income', 'Commodities', 'Asset Allocation', 'Alternatives', 'Currency', 'TOTALS']
['Starting Portfolio', 'sell']
```

Comment: For the first case.  I am getting: ['Equity', '\\', '\\', etc etc..., 'Fixed Income', '\\', '\\']  seems its being split in between by double back slashes

Comment: @rajn Yup it's not perfectly optimized I guess, just gets the work done somehow.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values, you might use an alternation to either match the words from the start of the string or get the words before  `&`

```
(?:^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*|[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*(?= &))
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^` Start of the line
  - `[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*` Match 1+ words with only chars A-Za-z
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*(?= &)` Match words followed by  `&`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HAJkD8/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1w00M6)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r'(?:^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*|[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*(?= &))'
rows_string = 'Equity & 1,638 & \\$3,227,305 & \\$2,649,208 & \\$3,270,402 & \\$3,114,298 & \\$3,173,369 & \\$2,978,769 & \\$3,016,161 & \\$2,807,840\\\\\nFixed Income & 420 & \\$765,856 & \\$661,395 & \\$824,603 & \\$792,579 & \\$794,224 & \\$783,793 & \\$719,307 & \\$630,298\\\\\nCommodities & 119 & \\$72,911 & \\$66,302 & \\$81,649 & \\$81,633 & \\$79,296 & \\$76,450 & \\$64,136 & \\$63,667\\\\\nAsset Allocation & 63 & \\$10,190 & \\$9,275 & \\$10,684 & \\$10,089 & \\$10,371 & \\$9,829 & \\$9,619 & \\$8,880\\\\\nAlternatives & 55 & \\$5,601 & \\$6,023 & \\$6,715 & \\$6,279 & \\$6,365 & \\$6,645 & \\$6,757 & \\$6,243\\\\\nCurrency & 34 & \\$311 & \\$2,014 & \\$1,665 & \\$1,743 & \\$1,683 & \\$1,666 & \\$1,722 & \\$2,058\\\\\nTOTALS & 2,329 & \\$4,082,173 & \\$3,394,217 & \\$4,195,718 & \\$4,006,620 & \\$4,065,308 & \\$3,857,151 & \\$3,817,700 & \\$3,518,986\\\\'
print(re.findall(pattern, rows_string, re.M))


rows_string2 = 'Starting Portfolio & sell & 21.39\\% & -0.91\\% & 1.52\\% & 9.29\\% & 9.72\\% & 14.89\\% & 38.21\\% & 55.4\\% &  & 90.86\\%\\\\'
print(re.findall(pattern, rows_string2, re.M))
```

Output

```
['Equity', 'Fixed Income', 'Commodities', 'Asset Allocation', 'Alternatives', 'Currency', 'TOTALS']
['Starting Portfolio', 'sell']
```

---

If all matches should be followed by  `&` you might simplify the pattern to

```
[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*(?= &)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1p8m1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target string (financial keyword) comes after a newline (or start of string) and before `&` you could do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\n|^)([A-Za-z ]+)\s&', s)
['Equity', 'Fixed Income', 'Commodities', 'Asset Allocation', 'Alternatives', 'Currency', 'TOTALS']
```

This uses some shortcuts, but depending on if you have more complex strings, such as "P&E", "Misc. Expenses", and such, the above might suffice.